# Similar to C++ access by reference?

Tags: f#, ocaml

I'm building a clustering algorithm in C++, but I don't deal well with OOP and the state of variables (member data) that change.  For an algorithm of some complexity, I find this an obstacle to my development.

So, I was thinking in changing the programming language, to one of the functional languages: Ocaml or F#.  Apart from having to change my mindset on how to approach programming, there's something that I need to be clarified.  In C++, I use a double end queue to slide a window of time through the data.  After some period of time, the oldest data is removed and newer data is appended. Data that is not yet too old remains in the double end queue.

Another, and more demanding task, is to compare properties of one of each objects. Each object is the data from a certain period of time. And if I have one thousand data objects at a certain time window, I need to compare each one to between none or twenty or thirty, depending.  And some properties of that object being compared may change as a result of this comparison. In C++, I do it all using references, which means that I access objects in memory, that they are never copied,  thus the algorithm runs at full speed (for my knowledge of C++).

I've been reading about functional programming, and the idea I get is that each function performs some operation and that original data (the input) is not changed.  This means that the language copies the data structure and performs the required transformation.  If so, using functional programming will delay the execution of the algorithm a great deal.  Is this correct?  If not, i.e., if there is a speedy way to perform transformation in data, is it possible to show me how to do it?  A very small example would be great.

I'm hoping to have some kind of facility. I've read that both Ocaml and F# are used in research and scientific projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a high level your question is whether using immutable data is slower than using mutable data. The answer to this is yes, it is slower in some cases. What's surprising (to me) is how small the penalty is. In most cases (in my experience) the extra time, which is often a log factor, is worth the extra modularity and clarity of using immutable data. And in numerous other cases there is no penalty at all.

The main reason that it's not as much slower as you would expect is that you can freely reuse any parts of the old data. There's no need to worry that some other part of the computation will change the data later: it's immutable!

For a similar reason, *all* accesses to immutable data are like references in C++. There's no need to make copies of data, as other parts of the computation can't change it.

If you want to work this way, you need to structure your data to get some re-use. If you can't easily do this, you may want to use some (controlled) mutation.

Both OCaml and F# are mixed-paradigm languages. They allow you to use mutable data if you want to.

The most enlightening account of operations on immutable data (IMHO) is Chris Okasaki's book [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504). (This Amazon link is for info only, not necessarily a suggestion to buy the book :-) You can also find much of this information in Okasaki's [Phd thesis](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

You can definitely implement a [pointer machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_machine) in OCaml and F#. So that you can store direct references, and update them. E.g.,

```
type 'a cell = {
   data : 'a;
   mutable lhs : 'a cell;
   mutable rhs : 'a cell;
}
```

In OCaml this will be represented as a pointer to a data structure, containing three words: a pointer to a data, and two pointers to sibling nodes:

```
   +--------+         +-------+      +-------+
   |  cell  |-------->| data  |----->|       |
   +--------+         |-------|      +-------+
                  +---|  lhs  |
                  |   |-------|
                  |   |  rhs  |--+
                  |   +-------+  |
                  |   +-------+  |   +-------+
                  +-->| data  |  --->| data  |
                      |-------|      |-------|
                      |  lhs  |      |  lhs  |
                      |-------|      |-------|
                      |  rhs  |      |  rhs  |
                      +-------+      +-------+
```

So, there is nothing special here. It is the same, as you can choose between persistent and imperative implementation in C++. But in C++ you usually pay a more significant cost for persistence, due to the lack of a support of a language itself. In OCaml there is a generative garbage collector, with very cheap allocation costs, and other optimizations.

So, yes, you can implement your data structure in a regular (imperative) way. But before doing this, you must be pretty sure, that you're ready to pay for this. It is much easier to reason about functional code, rather than imperative. This is actual the main reason, why people choose and use FP paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

> This means that the language copies the data structure and performs the required transformation

Not necessarily. If the objects are immutable (as they default to for F# record types, in C++ if all data members are `const` with no use of `mutable`) then taking a reference is fine.

> If so, using functional programming will delay the execution of the algorithm a great deal. Is this correct?

Even with the above, functional languages tend to support lazy operations. In F#, with the right data structures/methods, this will be the case. But it can also be eager.

An example (not terrible idiomatic, but trying to be clear):

```
let Square (is : seq<'t>) = is |> Seq.map(fun n -> n*n)
```

and then in

```
let res = [1; 2; 3; 4] |> Square
```

will not calculate any of the squares until you read the values from `re`.

Answer (score 1):

Its important to understand this in terms of two factors: mutation and sharing.
You are (seem to be) concentrated on the mutation aspect and seem to be neglecting sharing.

Take the standard list-append '@'; it copies the left arg and shares the right

So, yes it is true that you lose efficiency by copying but you correspondingly
gain by sharing.  And so if you arrange your data structures to maximze sharing
you stand to gain from that what you lose by immutability caused copying.

For the most part this 'just happens'.  However sometimes you need to tweak it.

Common example involving laziness in haskell:

```
ones = 1 : ones
```

this denotes an infinite list of 1s `[1,1,1,...]` 
And the implementation can
be expected to optimize it to a loop (circular-graph)

```
     +-----------+
     |           |
     V           |
+---------+      |
|         |      |
|    1    |-->---+
|         |
+---------+
```

However when we generalize it to an infinite list of x-es

```
repeat x = x : repeat x
```

the implementation has a harder time detecting the loop because the
variable `ones` has now become a (recursive) function-call `repeat x`

Change it to

```
repeat x = let repeat_x = x : repeat_x in repeat_x
```

and the loop (ie sharing) is reinstated.